# Laravel Elequent Relationships Issue with foreign key my data set has prefix

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, foreign-keys

Hi I am working with Laravel Elequent with one of my existing Mongodb database using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb.

this database has wired foregin keys data i.e

**Authors**

### ID   | name

1   | Xain

2   | Jhon

**Books**

### ID   | name    | authorId

1   | book1   | authors$1

2   | book2   | authors$1

3   | book3   | authors$2

Now when i use Laravels relationships in Authors i.e

$this->hasMany('App\Books', 'authorId', 'ID');

This do not work because of the prefix **authors$** in authorId

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I got some idea i need to override relationship functions i.e hasOne, hasMany etc  to modify query with regex for searching after $ sign but finding difficulty to search the right method to override :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue here are the details on how i did it Incase someone also encounter this type of issue.

This problem was because of using parse-server database and trying to access it from laravel's mongodb jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package

Parse-Server's database have a prefix in the data of forignkey's so the relationships like hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo seems not to work.

I Create a base model and extend all the models from that and the base model override relations methods i.e belongsTo

```
    namespace App;
    use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
    use App\Relations\BelongsTo;
    class Model extends Eloquent
    {
//
const CREATED_AT = '_created_at';
const UPDATED_AT = '_updated_at';
protected $primaryKey = '_id';

public function belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null)
{

    if (is_null($relation)) {
        list($current, $caller) = debug_backtrace(false, 2);

        $relation = $caller['function'];
    }

    // Check if it is a relation with an original model.
    if (! is_subclass_of($related, \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model::class)) {
        return parent::belongsTo($related, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
    }
    if (is_null($foreignKey)) {
        $foreignKey = Str::snake($relation).'_id';
    }

    $instance = new $related;
    $query = $instance->newQuery();
    $otherKey = $otherKey ?: $instance->getKeyName();
    return new BelongsTo($query, $this, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
}}
```

This belongsTO method actually call 
`BelongsTo`
which is 
`\Jenssegers\Mongodb\Relations\BelongsTo`
 so i also override this class 
        `getEagerModelKeys(array $models)` 
and
        `match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)`

Methods in my own 
`blongsTo` 
class 
         `App\Relations\BelongsTo;`
and explode the keys values with $ delimiter  inside these methods so it will remove whatever is before $ sign while matching the parent and child data.

```
    if (! is_null($value = explode('$', $model->{$this->foreignKey})[1])) 
    {
    $keys[] = $value;
    }

    $keyValue = explode('$', $model->{$foreign})[1];
    if (isset($dictionary[$keyValue])) {
    $model->setRelation($relation, $dictionary[$keyValue])
    ;}
```